# How to get intermediate results in Jax fori_loop mechanism

Tags: python, jax

I'm a newbie in Jax and not an Python expert either.

I'm running the jax version '0.2.14' on my mac laptop. Please find below a simple code, which at least for me give some results.

But, as stated in the comment `jax_metropolis_sampler` method, I would like to save intermediate results 'positions' but I do not figure out to do it propertly using `jax_fori_loop` and I guess doing like I have done is certainly horrible.

I'm pretty sure that someone can give me a better solution which exploit the jax parallelism. FOr the time beeing I have not look at forward/backward differentiation of my MixtureModel_jax.

Thanks in advance

```
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp
from functools import partial

class MixtureModel_jax():
    def __init__(self, locs, scales, weights, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.loc = jnp.array([locs]).T
        self.scale = jnp.array([scales]).T
        self.weights = jnp.array([weights]).T
        norm = jnp.sum(self.weights)
        self.weights = self.weights/norm

        self.num_distr = len(locs)

    def pdf(self, x):
        probs = jax.scipy.stats.norm.pdf(x,loc=self.loc, scale=self.scale)
        return jnp.dot(self.weights.T,probs).squeeze()
        
    def logpdf(self, x):
        log_probs = jax.scipy.stats.norm.logpdf(x,loc=self.loc, scale=self.scale)
        return jax.scipy.special.logsumexp(np.log(self.weights) + log_probs, axis=0)

@partial(jax.jit, static_argnums=(1,))
def jax_metropolis_kernel(rng_key, logpdf, position, log_prob):
    key, subkey = jax.random.split(rng_key)
    """Moves the chain by one step using the Random Walk Metropolis algorithm."""
  
    move_proposals = jax.random.normal(key, shape=position.shape) * 0.1
    proposal = position + move_proposals
    proposal_log_prob = logpdf(proposal)

    log_uniform = jnp.log(jax.random.uniform(subkey))
    do_accept = log_uniform < proposal_log_prob - log_prob

    position = jnp.where(do_accept, proposal, position)
    log_prob = jnp.where(do_accept, proposal_log_prob, log_prob)
    return position, log_prob

@partial(jax.jit, static_argnums=(1, 2))
def jax_metropolis_sampler(rng_key, n_samples, logpdf, initial_position):
    """Generate samples using the Random Walk Metropolis algorithm."""
    
    def mh_update(i, state):
        key, position, log_prob = state
        _, key = jax.random.split(key)
        new_position, new_log_prob = jax_metropolis_kernel(key, logpdf, position, log_prob)
        return (key, new_position, new_log_prob)

    logp = logpdf(initial_position)

    # Just return the last position
    #    rng_key, position, log_prob = jax.lax.fori_loop(0, n_samples, 
    #                                                    mh_update, 
    #                                                    (rng_key, initial_position, logp))
    #    return position

    
    # Porposal to save intermediate positions: slow and horrible I guess !
    spls = []
    state = (rng_key, initial_position, logp)
    
    for i in range(n_samples):
        state = mh_update(i, state)
        spls.append(state[1])


    return spls

mixture_gaussian_model = MixtureModel_jax([0,1.5],[0.5,0.1],[8,2])


n_dim = 1
n_samples = 50
n_chains = 7
rng_key = jax.random.PRNGKey(42)

rng_keys = jax.random.split(rng_key, n_chains)
initial_position = jnp.zeros((n_dim, n_chains))

run_mcmc = jax.vmap(jax_metropolis_sampler, 
                    in_axes=(0, None, None, 1),
                    out_axes=0)
positions = run_mcmc(rng_keys, n_samples, 
                 mixture_gaussian_modelbda x: mixture_gaussian_model.logpdf(x), 
                     initial_position)

print(len(positions))
print(positions[0].shape)
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this would be to carry the list of previous positions in the `fori_loop` function. Something like this:

```python
def mh_update(i, state):
    key, positions, log_prob = state
    _, key = jax.random.split(key)
    new_position, new_log_prob = jax_metropolis_kernel(key, logpdf, positions[-1], log_prob)
    positions = jnp.vstack([positions, new_position])
    return (key, positions, new_log_prob)

logp = logpdf(initial_position)
initial_state = (rng_key, initial_position[jnp.newaxis], logp)
rng_key, positions, log_prob = jax.lax.fori_loop(0, n_samples, 
                                                 mh_update, 
                                                 initial_state)
return positions
```

Comment: Well @jakedp I have tried and here is the error: 
```
TypeError: scan carry output and input must have identical types, got
(ShapedArray(int32[], weak_type=True), (ShapedArray(uint32[2]), ShapedArray(float32[2,1]), ShapedArray(float32[1])))
and
(ShapedArray(int32[], weak_type=True), (ShapedArray(uint32[2]), ShapedArray(float32[1,1]), ShapedArray(float32[1]))).

```
So I guess the progressive increase of "positions" size is forbidden by lax.fori_loop as stated in the doc. What do you think?

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. To work around it you could initialize the full array of positions at the start and fill a row on each iteration

Answer (score 0):

Here the solution I manage to get after @jakevdp hint

```
@partial(jax.jit, static_argnums=(1, 2))
def jax_metropolis_sampler(rng_key, n_samples, logpdf, initial_position):

       def mh_update_sol2(i, state):
        key, positions, log_prob = state
        _, key = jax.random.split(key)
        new_position, new_log_prob = jax_metropolis_kernel(key, logpdf, positions[i-1], log_prob)
        positions=positions.at[i].set(new_position)
        return (key, positions, new_log_prob)


    logp = logpdf(initial_position)
    all_positions = jnp.zeros((n_samples,)+initial_position.shape)
    initial_state = (rng_key,all_positions, logp)
    rng_key, all_positions, log_prob = jax.lax.fori_loop(1, n_samples, 
                                                 mh_update_sol2, 
                                                 initial_state)
    
    
    return all_positions

n_dim = 1
n_samples = 100_000
n_chains = 100
rng_key = jax.random.PRNGKey(42)

rng_keys = jax.random.split(rng_key, n_chains)
initial_position = jnp.zeros((n_dim, n_chains))

run_mcmc = jax.vmap(jax_metropolis_sampler, 
                    in_axes=(0, None, None, 1),
                    out_axes=0)
all_positions = run_mcmc(rng_keys, n_samples, 
                     lambda x: mixture_gaussian_model.logpdf(x), 
                     initial_position)

all_positions=all_positions.squeeze()
```

Then, after you can plot the 100 chains...

```
x_axis = jnp.arange(-3, 3, 0.001)
for i in range(all_positions.shape[0]):
    plt.hist(all_positions[i],bins=50, density=True, histtype='step',label=f"chain [{i}]");
plt.plot(x_axis,  mixture_gaussian_model.pdf(x_axis),'r-', lw=5, alpha=0.6, label='true pdf')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Thanks fro your help.